# Is there an integer-valued quadratic polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that $\{P(x,y)+2^k:\ x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \text{and}\ k\in\mathbb N\}=\mathbb Z^+$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I seek for very sparse representations of positive integers. Let
$$\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \mathbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}.$$
Recall that a polynomial $P(x,y)$ is integer-valued if $P(x,y)\in\mathbb Z$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

**Question 1.**  Is there an integer-valued quadratic polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that $\{P(x,y)+2^k:\ x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \text{and}\ k\in\mathbb N\}=\mathbb Z^+$?

I note that  $55832434$ is the first positive integer not represented by $x^2+y(3y+1)/2+2^k$ $(x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \text{and}\ k\in\mathbb N)$.

**Question 2.** Whether each positive integer $n$ can be written as
$$\frac{x(3x+1)}2+\frac{y(7y+1)}2+2^k$$
with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ and $k\in\mathbb N$?

This is positive for each $n=1,\ldots,2\times10^7$, see http://oeis.org/A343503.
I ever [proved](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11425-017-9354-4) that any $n\in\mathbb N$ can be written as $x^2+y(3y+1)/2+z(7z+1)/2$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$, and [conjectured](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2016.07.024) that $$\left\{x^4+\frac{y(3y+1)}2+\frac{z(7z+1)}2:\ x,y,z\in\mathbb Z\right\}=\mathbb N.$$

Your comments are welcome! In particular, Question 2 needs further check if you are good at computation.

Comment: The probability a number $n$ is represented by a quadratic polynomial should be proportional to $1/\sqrt{\log n}$, so the number of $k$ so that $n -2^k$ is represented should be proportional to $\sqrt{\log n}$, which if the statistics are Poisson-like would mean the probability $n$ cannot be represented is $e^{ - O( \sqrt{ \log n})}$, whose sum is infinte, suggesting that many numbers can't be represented. But maybe statistics are not Poisson-like...

Comment: The oeis link does not appear to be working yet.

Comment: The oeis sequence has been created, but not yet approved by the editors.

Comment: In contrast with the questions, I conjectured that any integer $n>1$ can be written as $2^x+\lfloor y^2/3\rfloor+\lfloor z^2/4\rfloor$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$, and this was verified for $n$ up to $10^{10}$; see http://oeis.org/A343397 .

Comment: Giovanni Resta has just informed me that he has found that  8558169401 is the first positive integer not of the form $x(3x+1)/2+y(7y+1)/2+2^k$. On the other hand, concerning my conjecture that any positve integer can be written as $x^6+y^3+z(3z+1)/2+2^k$ $(k,x,y\in\mathbb N,\ z\in\mathbb Z)$, he has verified it for $n$ up to $10^{10}$ without counterexamples found, see http://oeis.org/A343460 . Note that $1/2+1/3+1/6=1$.

Comment: I would guess for probabilistic reasons that no finite set of expressions of the form quadratic polynomial + an exponential covers all positive integers. However, small-number effects might imply that the first counterexample is quite large. If you want to find evidence against the probabilistic model / evidence for your conjecture, it might be worthwhile to calculate the mean and variance of the number of $k$ such that there exist $x$, $y$ representing $k$. If the variance is much less than the mean then the probabilistic model is likely oversimplified.

Comment: @Sawin Please note my conjecture on writing positive integers as $2^x+\lfloor y^2/3\rfloor+\lfloor z^2/4\rfloor$. Clearly, $$\{\lfloor y^2/3\rfloor:\ y\in\mathbb N\}=\{3y^2:\ y\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{y(3y+2):\ y\in\mathbb Z\}$$ and $$\{\lfloor z^2/4\rfloor:\ z\in\mathbb N\}=\{z^2:\ z\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{z(z+1):\ z\in\mathbb N\}.$$

Comment: Yes. I currently think this conjecture is wrong, but the first counterexamples just might be very large.

Comment: I get $8558169401=x(3x+1)/2+y(7y+1)/2+2^k$ for $x=51199, y=-36356, k=1$ or $x=34425, y=36383, k=31$, among more than 20 other solutions.

Comment: Yaakov, thank you for the clarification. So, Question 2 remains open as 8558169401 is not a counterexample to my conjecture.